# XSLT: use multiple or'd template matches to apply-templates

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an XML with multiple nodes with similar data in each.  I want to delete a specific attribute from each node (USER:IPADDRESS).  I've figured out how to chain together a number of elements using ors, simply leaving out the User="{@User}" match so it doesn't show up in the results:

XSL Snippet:

```
<xsl:template match="Creation | Test | Assignment | Modification | Repair | Termination">
<Creation CommitID="{@CommitID}" Date="{@Date}" BoardID="{@BoardID}">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</Creation>
</xsl:template>
```

Unsurprisingly, all of the node names after "Creation" get re-named to Creation because that's what I'm telling it to do.  How do I pass in the various matches so they're applied in the proper order in the results?  I know I can do a brute force way using identical XSL statements for each of the various matches (that's how I did it the first time), but there must be a more elegant method, it's just evading me.  I have millions & millions of lines of XML to process and this is just the first of many transforms I'm going to have to make.

I'm using msxsl V4.0 on a Win7 box to do my transforms if that's of any consequence.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BoardDatabase>
<Board_Data BoardID="1035">
    <Creation CommitID="12b" Date="2007-12-07T15:43:51" BoardID="1035" User="CSAGAN:192.168.1.177">
        <BoardDrawing>3B</BoardDrawing>
        <AssemblyDrawing>2010F</AssemblyDrawing>
        <Notes>PO Num 1959</Notes>
    </Creation>
    <Test CommitID="117" Date="2007-12-10T10:39:43" BoardID="1035" User="CSAGAN:192.168.1.183">
        <ElectricalTestData Result="FAIL" Version="IMM STD REVF">
            <AutomatedTest ReportVersion="1.0">
                <TestSetup>
                    <TestAppBuildDate>Dec 07 2007</TestAppBuildDate>
                    <VersionPath>c:\tests\versions\v12.txt</VersionPath>
                    <VersionNumber>1.2</VersionNumber>
                    <OperatorName>CSAGAN</OperatorName>
                    <StationID>PC-191-NDGrasse</StationID>
                    <JigSN>12345</JigSN>
                    <JigAssembly>42</JigAssembly>
                    <TestStartTime>2007-12-10 10:34:17</TestStartTime>
                </TestSetup>
            </AutomatedTest>
        </ElectricalTestData>
    </Test>
    <Assignment CommitID="1c1f" User="JRandi:192.168.1.162" Date="2008-09-30T07:36:52" BoardID="1035">
        <Notes>Boardset failed etest twice, no problem log entry/repair attempts made.</Notes>
    </Assignment>
    <Modification CommitID="2bb7" User="JRandi:192.168.1.162" Date="2009-03-11T13:31:21" BoardID="1035">
        <AssemblyDrawing>2001G</AssemblyDrawing>
        <Notes>Cornelius upgraded boardset to rev. G</Notes>
    </Modification>
</Board_Data>
</BoardDatabase>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="Creation | Test | Assignment | Modification | Repair | Termination">
<Creation CommitID="{@CommitID}" Date="{@Date}" BoardID="{@BoardID}">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</Creation>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Latest XSL using @DevNull's solution that doubles size of original file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<!-- Answer from Stack Overflow that only strips out the IP Address from the User attribute. -->
<xsl:template match="@User">
  <xsl:attribute name="User">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(.,':')"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Latest XSL from @Dimitre's solution that takes a very long time to process (still running after more than 30 minutes, but file is still growing):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "*[contains('|Creation|Test|Assignment|Modification|Repair|Termination|',concat('|', name(), '|'))
]/@user"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. You may be interested in a slightly better solution, which is shorter and adaptable for an indefinitely long list of element names -- that even could be passed as a parameter to the transformation.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try changing your template to this:

```
<xsl:template match="Creation|Test|Assignment|Modification|Repair|Termination">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(name()='User')]|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

You'll notice it looks a lot like your identity template with a predicate added to `@*`.

Also, if you wanted to strip all `User` attributes no matter what the element was, you could use this template instead:

```
<xsl:template match="@User"/>
```

Here's one more way (only stripping from `Creation` and `Test` for brevity)

```
<xsl:template match="@User[..[self::Creation or self::Test]]"/>
```

---

**Answer to comment**

Use this template instead:

```
<xsl:template match="@User">
    <xsl:attribute name="User">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(.,':')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Perfect!  Today's the first time I've ever used XSLT, so I'm climbing the curve & know I've got a lot to learn.  I'm literally going through "XSLT For Dummies" right now.  Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: @delliottg - Nice work so far. You're on the right track with using an identity transform and then overriding it when you need to. A lot of beginners go straight to `xsl:for-each` :-) I'll also add another option you could use just for variety.

Comment: This should probably be a different question, but what if I just wanted to strip out the IP addresses from each User attribute?  So User="JRandi:192.168.1.162" would become User="JRandi".  Re: xsl:for-each, I've spent a lot of time yesterday & today reading answers from people like Dimitre Novatchev & Tomalak and learned that wasn't a good way to go.

Comment: @delliottg - You can't go wrong following advice from those 2. I added an update to cover stripping out the IP from the `User` attribute.

Comment: I used your answer XSL above to run a transform against one of my larger files (140mb), and the resultant file was slightly over doubled in size (283mb).  I thought possibly it had just appended the results to the first transform's results, but that's not the case and I don't see any simple reason for the file to have grown so large (it won't open in Notepad++, I have to open it in gVIM to view it).  Any ideas?

Comment: @delliottg - Is there anything obvious when you view it? Whitespace differences? Indenting/formatting differences? Try adding `<xsl:output indent="no"/>` and `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` as children of `xsl:stylesheet` and see if that makes any difference. Also, can you update your question with the latest version of your XSL?

Comment: I've got Dimitre's solution running in the background, so I can't inspect the file, but I'll run yours again in a different window so I can answer your questions.  I've updated my original question with the two XSL files I've currently got from you & him.  Thanks for your continued support, I appreciate it, and I'll get back with the answers to your questions shortly.

Comment: @delliottg - The XSL you're using isn't changing anything but the value of the `User` attribute. I think the size difference is from formatting. I think if you add the `xsl:output` and `xsl:strip-space` from my comment above, you shouldn't see a size increase.

Comment: I ran the transform as you asked, and you're largely correct, the original file was 140,377 kb, and the resultant file was 142,319 kb but it took about 50 minutes to run (like Dimitre's transform below).  I am unsure how I got such a short time with your version earlier, although the transform was somewhat different (and I have copies so I can test).  It's OK if the transforms take this long since I can run them when I leave at night.  I don't understand why this one increases file size since I'm deleting data from each CommitID attribute although it's just about 1.4% more.

Comment: Figured out what was causing the file size to double, it was encoding the XML as UTF-16 Little Endian, if I change to     `xsl:output encoding="UTF-8"`, the resultant size drops to half (a 23mb file gets transformed to 16mb instead of 32mb) which makes more sense.  But that file shows up in Notepad++ as "ANSI as UTF-8" instead of UTF-8 like the source XML.  I haven't been able to figure out why that's happening yet.  Getting a lot closer to the desired results though, thanks for the continued support.  Edit:  both have DOS/Windows endings, I thought of 'nix endings a while ago & checked that.

Answer (score 4):

**I would use what I consider even a better solution:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "*[contains('|Creation|Test|Assignment|Modification|Repair|Termination|',
             concat('|', name(), '|'))
   ]/@user"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Do note**:

1. We only use a single template overriding the identity rule. Its body is empty.
2. The list of element names is presented as a pipe-delimited string and for long lists this saves significant space -- also, such a string can be passed as an external parameter to the transformation, thus making it maximum generic.
3. This transformation is in completely "push style".

Comment: thanks for the solution.  I have a couple of questions, I'm running this against a fairly large file (140mb), and it's been running for more than 10 minutes now (not exactly sure when I started), where DevNull's solution runs in less than a minute.  I can see that your solution is still processing because I can see the file size of the resultant file growing, but it's taking a long time.  Do you have an idea why the time difference is so great?  There are problems with the other transform as well, please see my comments for that one.

Comment: @delliottg, Both solutions should have roughly the same efficiency. I have the feeling that you are trying to adapt these solutions to a different XML format and it is likely that you don't do this adaptation in a correct way. It is recommended to provide a fully representative (but small) source XML document and the exact wanted result -- then we would be able to give a solution that doesn't need to be adapted.

Comment: I attempted to do exactly that with some obfuscation of data, jig names, etc as well as severely truncated file with an example of each type of "CommitID" in the example file.  The format of the example I've provided is very close to the actual data (which I am unable to provide due to company restrictions), however I can't discount that there may be things in the data I'm not aware of (only been here 4 weeks) and the files are huge.  I will take some time to construct a more complete example of the XML & append it to the original question.  Thanks for your help, I appreciate it.