# xslt template match multiple elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to remove all empty elements with their parents but for some nodes only. I was trying following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13317316/808891) but I wasn't able to do that.

For this specific example below nodes only I'd like to process:

- section[@desc='a']
- section[@desc='b']
- remove

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<item>
    <perm desc="item_1">
        <section desc="a">
            <delete></delete>
            <nondelete>a</nondelete>
        </section>
        <section desc="b">
            <delete></delete>
            <nondelete>a</nondelete>
        </section>
        <section desc="c">
            <delete></delete>
            <nondelete>a</nondelete>
        </section>        
        <details>
            <firstname desc="Name">John</firstname>
            <lastname desc="Last"></lastname>
            <phone desc="phone"></phone>            
        </details>
    </perm>    
    <remove>
        <delete></delete>        
    </remove>
</item>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> 

<xsl:template match="section[@desc='a']|section[@desc='b']|remove/*[not(self::perm)][not(descendant::text()[normalize-space()])]" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<item>
    <perm desc="item_1">
        <section desc="a">
            <nondelete>a</nondelete>
        </section>
        <section desc="b">
            <nondelete>a</nondelete>
        </section>
        <section desc="c">
            <delete></delete>
            <nondelete>a</nondelete>
        </section>
        <details>
            <firstname desc="Name">John</firstname>
            <lastname desc="Last"/>
            <phone desc="phone"/>
        </details>
    </perm>
</item>
```

What do I need to change in the `template match` to accomplish this?

**Update**

I was able to almost achieve what I wanted with below XSLT, not very sure is the best way though:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="section[@desc='a']|section[@desc='b']|remove">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(not(@*) and normalize-space()='')]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Only thing is that the parent if all child elements are empty remains there, like the `remove` parent element in this case. I've also noticed that this doesn't work either if children are present within these elements (no changes to the children). How can I get the parent to be also removed in this case and the same action in any children they might contain?

```
<section desc="b">
    <child>
        <a>12</a>
        <b></b>
    </child>
    <delete></delete>
    <nondelete>a</nondelete>
</section>
```

Comment: Please explain the required logic in detail. Which nodes exactly are "some nodes only"?

Comment: Please refer to my updated post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53418554/808891), I was finally able to get the result I wanted:

Source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<item>
    <perm desc="item_1">
        <section desc="a">
            <delete></delete>
            <nondelete>a</nondelete>
        </section>
        <section desc="b">
            <child>
                <a>12</a>
                <b></b>
            </child>
            <delete></delete>
            <nondelete>a</nondelete>
        </section>
        <section desc="c">
            <delete></delete>
            <nondelete>a</nondelete>
        </section>        
        <details>
            <firstname desc="Name">John</firstname>
            <lastname desc="Last"></lastname>
            <phone desc="phone"></phone>            
        </details>
    </perm>    
    <remove>
        <delete></delete>        
    </remove>
</item>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[ancestor-or-self::section[@desc='a'] or ancestor-or-self::section[@desc='b'] or ancestor-or-self::remove][not(string())]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<item>
   <perm desc="item_1">
      <section desc="a">
         <nondelete>a</nondelete>
      </section>
      <section desc="b">
         <child>
            <a>12</a>
         </child>
         <nondelete>a</nondelete>
      </section>
      <section desc="c">
         <delete/>
         <nondelete>a</nondelete>
      </section>
      <details>
         <firstname desc="Name">John</firstname>
         <lastname desc="Last"/>
         <phone desc="phone"/>
      </details>
   </perm>
</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<item>
    <perm desc="item_1">
        <section desc="a">
            <delete></delete>
            <nondelete>a</nondelete>
        </section>
        <section desc="b">
            <delete></delete>
            <nondelete>a</nondelete>
        </section>
        <details>
            <firstname desc="Name">John</firstname>
            <lastname desc="Last"></lastname>
            <phone desc="phone"></phone>
        </details>
    </perm>
    <remove>
        <delete></delete>
    </remove>
</item>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(@*) and normalize-space()='']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<item>
  <perm desc="item_1">
    <section desc="a">
      <nondelete>a</nondelete>
    </section>
    <section desc="b">
      <nondelete>a</nondelete>
    </section>
    <details>
      <firstname desc="Name">John</firstname>
      <lastname desc="Last" />
      <phone desc="phone" />
    </details>
  </perm>
</item>
```

Comment: if I add a new `<section desc="c">` which I don't want to get processed, it gets processed as well. Any chance to specify the ones I want?